# Laravel UPDATE query with multiple where conditions not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am fed up. Simple update method not working. It should update record matching the given item_id,restaurant_id and avil_date.

```
public function updateWeeklyItem(){
        
        $item_id=request('item_id');
        $restaurant_id=request('restaurant_id');
        $avil_date=request('avil_date');


        weekly_item::where(function($query) use ($item_id, $restaurant_id,$avil_date){
            $query->where('item_id', $item_id)
        ->where('restaurant_id', $restaurant_id)
        >where('avil_date', $avil_date);
         })->update ([
        'start_time'=>request('start_time'),
        'end_time'=>request('end_time'),
        'tiffin-switch'=>request('tiffin-switch'),
        'lunch-switch'=>request('lunch-switch'),
        'snacks-switch'=>request('snacks-switch'),
        'dinner-switch'=>request('dinner-switch'),
        'special-switch'=>request('special-switch'),
        'extend-avil'=>request('extend-avil'),
        'unit'=>request('unit'),
        'quantity'=>request('quantity')
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: If theres no error, then I suspect you have another code that updated the same table after updating your table.Your table was eventually updated twice.check your else if statement

Answer (score -1):

Use This Code:

```php
    public function updateWeeklyItem(Request $request) {
        $item_id       =    $request->item_id;
        $restaurant_id =    $request->restaurant_id;
        $avil_date     =    $request->avil_date;

        $item = weekly_item::where(function($query) use ($item_id, $restaurant_id,$avil_date) {
            $query->where('item_id', $item_id)
                ->where('restaurant_id', $restaurant_id)
                ->where('avil_date', $avil_date);
         })->first();
        
        $item_array = (
            'start_time'     =>  $request->start_time,
            'end_time'       =>  $request->end_time,
            'tiffin-switch'  =>  $request->tiffin-switch,
            'lunch-switch'   =>  $request->lunch-switch,
            'snacks-switch'  =>  $request->snacks-switch,
            'dinner-switch'  =>  $request->dinner-switch,
            'special-switch' =>  $request->special-switch,
            'extend-avil'    =>  $request->extend-avil,
            'unit'           =>  $request->unit,
            'quantity'       =>  $request->quantity
        );

        $item->update($item_array);

        return $item;
    }
```